# Liferay link showing WAR name and jsp URI

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I set up a button like this:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="editTeamURL">
        <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/myteam/editTeam.jsp" />
<!--        <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/myteam/editTeam.jsp" /> -->
    </portlet:renderURL>
    <aui:layout cssClass="buttons-wrapper">
        <aui:column columnWidth="100">
            <aui:a cssClass="btn" id="UpdateRole" name="UpdateRole" href="<%= editTeamURL %>"><%=LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "edit-team") %></aui:a>
        </aui:column>
    </aui:layout>
```

The problem is, my destination URL ends up being like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/group/invitations?p_p_id=myteam_WAR_MYPORTLET&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_myteam_WAR_MYPORTLET_jspPage=%2Fhtml%2Fmyteam%2FeditTeam.jsp
```

How can I hide WAR name and jsp URI from this link? I fear this might be a security hole and prone to attacks of some kind (also, makes the URLs look pretty ugly)

EDIT: this is what I've done:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>my-team</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>

    <friendly-url-mapper-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultFriendlyURLMapper</friendly-url-mapper-class>
    <friendly-url-mapping>team</friendly-url-mapping>
    <friendly-url-routes>com/myapp/routes.xml</friendly-url-routes>

    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>
        /js/main.js
    </footer-portlet-javascript>
    <css-class-wrapper>my-team-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

route.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 6.1.0//EN"
"http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_6_1_0.dtd">

<routes>
    <route>
        <pattern>/edit</pattern>
        <implicit-parameter name="jspPage">
            /html/myteam/editTeam.jsp
        </implicit-parameter>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much solved this problem yourself. Once you set-up a friendly-url mapper in your portlet, all links will be rendered using the pattern that you define in the mapper - thus hiding the name of the war and the destination.

So read up on the *well documented* friendly-url feature.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what version of `Liferay` you are using. However, it seems your problem can be solved with usage of `Friendly URL`. Here is an official [doc](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/adding-friendly-url-mapping-to-the-portlet).

Quotation from doc:

> The feature is called friendly URL mapping. It takes unnecessary parameters out of the URL and allows you to place the important parameters in the URL path, rather than in the query string. To add this functionality, first edit liferay-portlet.xml and add the following lines directly after  and before  (remove the line breaks):

```
<friendly-url-mapper-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultFriendlyURLMapper</friendly-url-mapper-class>
<friendly-url-mapping>my-greeting</friendly-url-mapping>
<friendly-url-routes>com/liferay/samples/my-greeting-friendly-url-routes.xml</friendly-url-routes>
```

> Next, create the file:

```
my-greeting-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/samples/my-greeting-friendly-url-routes.xml
```

> Place the following content into the new file (remove the line break after {mvcPathName}.jsp):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 6.1.0//EN"
"http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_6_1_0.dtd">

<routes>
   <route>
       <pattern>/{mvcPathName}</pattern>
       <generated-parameter name="mvcPath">/{mvcPathName}.jsp\
       </generated-parameter>
   </route>
</routes>
```

> Redeploy your portlet, refresh the page, and try clicking either of the links again.

Comment: This sounds like the solution, but I can't get it to work. I'm using Liferay 6.2. Also this seems to change the url after clicking on the link, but I would like the link to be the friendly url already

Comment: @MichelReap unfortunately, I'm not a Liferay expert, I just used it for a while and noticed `friendly urls`. Sorry I can't help you more with that issue.